# Trying to filter users that have any order with the status id equal to 2 yet getting other users total as 0

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, left-join, aggregate-functions

```sql
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total, id 
    FROM (SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status_id=2) 
    RIGHT JOIN users ON users.id = orders.courier
```

I'm getting this error

> #1054 - Unknown column 'orders.courier' in 'on clause'

Comment: You must use a alias for a subquerie. Change it to ... (SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status_id=2) AS O RIGHT JOIN.... ON USER.ID = O.COURIER

Comment: Put a sample on http://sqlfiddle.com/ then i will cottect it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select user_id
from orders
having sum(status_id = 2)  >= 1
group by user_id
```

This will give you all `user_id`s that have at least one order with `status_id = 2` (assuming that the column in `orders` that store the id of the user is called `user_id`).

If you want to list all users that ordered and count how many orders they have with `status_id = 2`:

```
select user_id, sum(status_id = 2) count_status_2
from orders
group by user_id
```

And if you want even users that never ordered:

```
select u.user_id, coalesce(sum(o.status_id = 2), 0) count_status_2
from users u
left join orders o on o.user_id = u.user_id
group by u.user_id
```